# undercore _.sortBy not sorting array objects correctly

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```js
var Arr = [
             {size: "8"},
             {size: "9"},
             {size: "10"},
             {size: "7"},
             {size: "6"}
          ]

console.log(_.sortBy(Arr, 'size'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

I created a sample of my code above that is not sorting correctly base on my given array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `size` to a number:

```js
var Arr = [
             {size: "8"},
             {size: "9"},
             {size: "10"},
             {size: "7"},
             {size: "6"}
          ]

console.log(_.sortBy(Arr, (obj) => parseInt(obj.size)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To elaborate a little, with them being strings, they get sorted alphabetically. “1”, “10”, “100”, “11”, “2”, “20”, “3”.

Answer (score 2):

Your size attr is of type `String`, not `Number`. In JS, values in quotes (`"` or `'`) indicate a `String` type.

Make them numbers and it will sort properly.

```js
var Arr = [
   {size: 8 },
   {size: 9 },
   {size: 10},
   {size: 7 },
   {size: 6 }
]

console.log(_.sortBy(Arr, 'size'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a scenario of strings not being interpreted as numbers as intended. Here are two ways to cast using the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator, both with and without _:

```js
var Arr = [
             {size: "8"},
             {size: "9"},
             {size: "10"},
             {size: "7"},
             {size: "6"}
          ]

console.log(Arr.sort((a, b) => +a.size - +b.size));
console.log(_.sortBy(Arr, o => +o.size));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```